# Is that possible to call a Main() method outside of an assembly..if it is yes means how it could be?

Tags: c#-4.0, console-application

Is that possible to call a Main() method outside of an assembly.if it is yes means how it could be.

Comment: why do you want to call `main` method ? Your operation system is already doing that

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're thinking about with the phrase "outside of an assembly" - could you try to more carefully describe what situation you're trying to set up?

Comment: if we are using the namesapce called name1,in that we had main method....now we are creating new namespace called name2....Now i included name1 into name2 via "using" comment.. Here is my  doubt is can we call name1 main method in name2..

Comment: Sounds like something you could try out for yourself in a few minutes. Also, assembly and namespace are two *separate* concepts. You need to be clear that an assembly can contain types in multiple namespaces, and multiple assemblies can contain types for a single namespace.